# Can EventBridge archive store only failed events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

I'm explorer EventBridge Archive. For now we have an EventBridge setup with a DLQ. When the redrive policy fails for an event, it appears on that DLQ. From there we can pick up only failed events.

Is there a way to retrieve only failed events using EventBridge Archive or will it always contain all events (or all events matching a certain rule)?

Comment: Amazon EventBridge Archive doesn't inherently differentiate between successful and failed events. It is designed to capture and store all events that match the specified rule(s) or pattern(s) in your Amazon EventBridge event bus. This includes both successful events and events that may have triggered a DLQ (Dead Letter Queue) due to a redrive policy failure. 
One approach could be to modify your event processing logic to send a copy of failed events to a dedicated event bus or stream, and then configure the EventBridge Archive to capture events from that dedicated event bus or stream.